# Invite Facebook Friends

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to include send invire request from my website. Can I use below API for the same. The documentation only specifies games.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/requests/v2.1

Will facebook block my app if I use it for non gaming application/website.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#invite_to_app

App Requests are for games on Facebook only, if you want to invite users to visit your website use the following possibilities:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/send-button
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog

After all you want to invite them to visit your website and not to play your game or use your app.